# Pronunciation of 800 / 八百

Tags: pronunciation, numbers

A Japanese textbook labels the pronunciation of 800 / 八百 as はっ**ぴ**ゃく, but elsewhere labels the pronunciation of 5,800 / 五千八百 as ごせんはっ**び**ゃく (emphases added). Should the first syllable of 百 be ぴゃ or びゃ following 八, or does it depend? How to determine which to use?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It should be always はっぴゃく [happyaku]. If they say はっびゃく [habbyaku], it’s a typo.